# Re-keying [key] to be more useful

Tags: discussion, tags, burnination-request

Recently, I discovered the existence of [key](https://askubuntu.com/questions/tagged/key).

This tag is currently being used for both cryptographic keys (SSH/GPG/RSA/etc.) as well as keys on one's keyboard.

A tag that functions like this has, in my opinion, no reason to exist. The tag is simply too generic and is better handled by other tags.

For the cryptographic example, most questions can be tagged [ssh](https://askubuntu.com/questions/tagged/ssh), [gpg](https://askubuntu.com/questions/tagged/gpg), etc. For keyboards, valid tags would be (obviously) [keyboard](https://askubuntu.com/questions/tagged/keyboard), [keyboard-shortcuts](https://askubuntu.com/questions/tagged/keyboard-shortcuts), etc.

Due to the nature of this tag, it's probably bad to synonymize it and it's bad to keep around. However, I don't think blacklisting is (yet) a viable option. Perhaps just deleting/retagging the existing tag will suffice?

Comment: Seems it's also being used for questions about small USB storage devices. Definitely a bad tag for our site.

Comment: Also [tag:apt] for the key errors when updating

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As of now, there are no questions tagged [key](https://askubuntu.com/questions/tagged/key) on the main site.

Thanks to everyone who helped!

Now, to deal with [keys](https://askubuntu.com/questions/tagged/keys)...

Answer (score 4):

IMHO it seems that the recent edit of [key](https://askubuntu.com/questions/tagged/key) info by [Tim](https://askubuntu.com/users/186134/tim) should do the job of steering people away from using this tag. At last check there were only about 60 questions using it. Editing to remove/replace it on those questions using it would seem logical to me due to it's complete lack of precision. Those who follow [key](https://askubuntu.com/questions/tagged/key) may have a different view. I don't.

Comment: I'm editing 10 every few days. It should be gone soon.

Comment: @Tim I think I only managed a couple due to other commitments. I'll chip in when/where I can.